# How to place multiple const objects from multiple translation units sorted in one memory block?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, sections

I am developing firmware for some devices and each of them contain configuration objects which values are allowed to be changed by an external application. Here is example of such object:

```
struct TObjectParams
{
   ObjectId       ID;            // enum
   void*          Data;          // pointer to configuration data
   unsigned short Length;        // size of data

   TAccessControl AccessControl; //object access control
};
```

Each instance of `TObjectParams` is const and cannot be changed during runtime.
Firmware consists of multiple modules and each of them comes with its own configuration objects. It is done so, because different devices can contain different modules and forcing each device to contain all off the objects would be waste of resources.
My goal is to group all the objects into one place (array or single section) and have them sorted there by `ID` number (sorting will significantly reduce search complexity from `O(n)` to `O(log n)`.

My first idea was to use `constexpr` to register object (in object's constructor) and during compile time create `constexpr` array with all objects. But as far as I know it would work only if all of the  objects were in the same translation unit.

My second idea is to use `__attribute__((used, section("objects_section")))` and now I am ensured that linker won't remove any defined object and all of them would be in same section. The problem is sorting. Is there any way to force linker to sort these objects? Or maybe it is possible by editig `.elf` file? I know that I can easily dump `objects_section`, sort it (by own app) and update through `objcopy` but it will totally mess debugging experience and direct call of any object because updating section content won't update symbols addresses (or maybe I am wrong).

Do you know how to not only update section content but also symbols addresses? Or maybe you know better approach to such a problem? I am open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to force linker to sort these objects?

No, especially given that the ordering criteria can be arbitrary.

However, you don't really need to sort the objects: you can sort an array of pointers to the objects (created during initialization), and do subsequent searches on that array.

> I know that I can easily dump objects_section, sort it (by own app) and update through objcopy but it will totally mess debugging experience and direct call of any object because updating section content won't update symbols addresses (or maybe I am wrong).

That's not the *only* thing `objcopy` will mess up. It will also mess up *correctness*: your `Data` member points to some other data, which means there are relocation records associated with each instance. If you sort `TObjectParams` instances without updating the relocation records, your `Data` pointers will point to the wrong configuration data after `objcopy`.

**Update:**

> that solution is partially satisfying.

If you can include configuration data *directly* into `TObjectParams`, they will become larger and the overhead of pointers smaller.

If configuration data itself has no pointers to other data, then you *can* sort the section contents directly, and avoid the overhead altogether.

If you can't get rid of pointers, then you would have to write a custom ELF manipulation tool which will sort the data and associated relocation records. Such a tool could also update the symbol section to address debugging.

However, I think there is a significantly simpler solution, at least in case where there is a single instances of `TObjectParams` in a given `.o` file (or when a given `.o` is guaranteed to only have consecutive `ID`s and `.o` files do not overlap in the `ID`s that are contained in them):

1. Put all the  `TObjectParams` in a separate section as you do now.
2. Link the binary. This will produce a binary with unsorted section, and the only reason for this link is to obtain a list of objects that went into this binary.

   If you already maintain such a list separately, this step can be skipped.
3. For each object file in the list from step 2 (`foo.o`), use `objcopy` to get two new objects: one with just the section of interest (`foo_w.o`), and one with that section removed (`foo_x.o`).
4. Sort the list of `{foo,bar,baz}_w.o` by the `ID` that is contained within.
5. Perform final link, using `{foo,bar,baz}_x.o` in any order, and `{foo,bar,baz}_w.o` in the *sorted* order. The linker will not generally reorder contents of the section, and that link should produce desired final binary.

Comment: I think that solution is partially satisfying. There can be hundreds of such objects and currently size of each ```TObjectParams``` is 12B (flash memory, because object is const) and size of each pointer to it is 4B (ram). In case embedded firmware, where resources are very limited, storing pointers and sorting them in runtime will cost 1/3 of alread used memory. I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Russin your updated solution looks pretty good, but I think that you assume that one source file contains only one object. How about multiple objects in one source file?

Comment: @legier I did assume a single `TObjectParams` in a single `.o` file. I don't have a solution for the case where `foo.o` has `TObjectParams` with `ID` 1 and 3, and `bar.o` has `ID`s 2 and 4. You'll have to either restructure your sources or write an `ELF` manipulation tool for that case.